# Is there a more Pythonic way of handling dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am utilising the fact that for python >= 3.7 elements in a dictionary are retrieved in the order of insertion.

I want to create a dict where the first *skip* items contain zero; after that, they take the relevant values  from a master dict

```
dict_1 = {
    'a1' : 11,
    'a2' : 12,
    'a3' : 13,
    'b1' : 14,
    'b2' : 15,
    'c1' : 16,
}

skip = 3

dict_2 = {}
for item in range(skip):
    dict_2[str(item)] = 0

index = 0
for key, item in dict_1.items():
    index += 1
    if index > skip:
        dict_2[key] = item

print(dict_2)
```

> {'0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, 'b1': 14, 'b2': 15, 'c1': 16}

For the avoidance of doubt, the keys in dict_2 are different from the keys in dict_1 for items < skip.

This does what I want, but it is inelegant. Is there a more pythonic approach I could take?

Comment: Notice that your dict_2 first 3 keys also got changed, is that you want? Or just the first 3 `skip` values, not `keys`?  Please confirm.

Comment: I want the keys and values to change - the current output is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{(xy[0] if i>=skip else str(i)):(xy[1] if i>=skip else 0)  for i,xy in enumerate(iter(dict_1.items()))}
```

However let us remember that [Simple is better than complex and Readability counts.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020)

Comment: Your results - {'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'b1': 0, 'b2': 15, 'c1': 16}?!   It should be -   if i `>=` skip  else....   Common offset error?

Comment: The first `skip` keys should also be `str(i)`

Comment: You both are right. I did not notice the key and offset. I just wanted to show that the iterator with enumerate can be used. I will edit.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it does what I want and I've learned something useful. However, I won't use it - as you say Readability counts and I can come back to my ugly solution next year and understand it straight away

Comment: `xy` is quite ambiguous. It will add readability (to an already unreadable line) if you changed to `for i, (key, value) in enumerate...` and then replace `xy[0]` with `key` and `xy[1]` with `value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid the `if` check:

```py
from itertools import islice

dict_2 = {str(item): 0 for item in range(skip)}

for key, item in islice(dict_1.items(), skip, None):
    dict_2[key] = item
```

Alternatively, combine both options to one loop, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(dict_1.items()):
    if i < skip:
        dict_2[str(i)] = 0
    else:
        dict_2[key] = value
```

Comment: Nice usage of `islice` - iterator of iterable ... Very *Pythonic*!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you have in mind (*did not* get your confirm), try to make minimum change to your original code, and keep the orig. `keys` intact as well:

```
skip = 3

dict_2 = dict_1.copy()   # create a new copy for updating


for k, v in dict_1.items():
    if skip > 0:
        dict_2[k] = 0
    skip -= 1


print(dict_2)
```